# In MQL4 the variable doesn't change

Tags: variables, mql4

I am starting to learn MQL4 and wanted to write a simple program for practice. When I open a long position, the positions variable is supposed to take the value 1, and when I take a short position, the positions variable is supposed to take the value -1. Unfortunately, after the loop is executed, the variable is still 0. What am I doing wrong? PS. Close_Trade is my internal function and works well.

```
void OnTick()
  {
   
     {
      double stoch= iStochastic(NULL,0,14,3,3,0,1,0,0);
      int number_of_order= OrdersTotal();
      static int positions=0;
      if(number_of_order==0)
        {
         if(stoch<=20)
           {
            int purchase_order=OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_BUY,0.01,Ask,0,0,0,NULL,0,0,clrNONE);
            positions++;
           }
         else
            if(stoch>=80)
              {
               int sales_order=OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_SELL,0.01,Bid,0,0,0,NULL,0,0,clrNONE);
               positions--;
              }
        }
       Alert(positions);
     if(stoch>70 && positions==1)
        {
         Close_Trade();
         positions--;
        }
      if(stoch<30&&positions==-1)
        {
         Close_Trade();
         positions++;
        }
     }

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I added a static to the position variable, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: delete `static int positions=0;` from `OnTick` function and write out and before `OnTick` function. No need to write `static`.

**Long answer**:

***Please put the line numbers in the next questions***

However, the problem is in the line

```
    static int positions=0;
```

Behold

The process of your program is that your code is executed once for each market tick

1. In `double stoch= iStochastic(NULL,0,14,3,3,0,1,0,0);` the value of the `stoch` variable is set, for example, we assume its value is equal to 15.
2. In `int number_of_order= OrdersTotal();`, `number_of_order` takes a value equal to `OrdersTotal()`, we assume that you do not have an open order and the value of this variable is equal to 0.
3. In `static int positions=0;` the position variable takes the value 0.
4. Since you don't have an open order, the program enters the `if(number_of_order==0)`.
5. Because the `stock` value is below 20, so program enters `if(stoch<=20)` and opens an order, and `position` increases by one unit and becomes equal to 1.
6. In `Alert(positions);` it gives a warning and outputs the value of the `position`, which is 1 (it is useless to warn the value of the position variable in every market tick, write the program in such a way that it alert if the value of the `position` changes. I think this is better).
7. Because the value of the `stoch` is 15 and the value of the `position` is 1, the program does not enter the remaining two `if` statements and the value of the `position` is still equal to 1.

The program ends and waits for the next market tick (which is very short). At the beginning of the next tick, the `stoch` variable is reset with `ouble stoch= iStochastic(NULL,0,14,3,3,0,1,0,0);`. In `int number_of_order= OrdersTotal();`, `number_of_order` becomes 1. The value of the `position`, which is equal to 1, will be equal to 0 with `static int positions=0;`.

This is the problem with your program You have to delete `static int positions=0;` from `OnTick` function and write out and before it. No need to write `static`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now everything is working properly. If I have another question I won't forget the line numbering :)